# E: Package 'guile-1.8-dev' has no installation candidate this is an error i got

Tags: apt

I have `apt-get` 0.7.23.1 on host machine. I do not have root, thus not able to update it, or install other packages.

I want to download `.deb` packages with it, but neither

```
apt-get -d bash
```

(Invalid operation bash)

nor

```
apt-get -d install bash
```

(do not have root)

work.

On my home machine with a newer version of `apt-get` I can

```
apt-get download bash
```

and it does exactly what I want it to.

How can I perform the same on the host machine?

Comment: You always need to be root to install packages.

Comment: @Takkat I don't need to install them

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The command `apt-get download` wasn't added until version 0.8.11 of `apt`. It was first available in Ubuntu 11.04 (which uses apt 0.8.13.2). I'm not sure what you're running as AFAICT no supported version of Ubuntu contains version 0.7.23.1 of `apt`. You should really have the system administrator upgrade the machine. (I know, not very helpful.)

It's not clear from your question whether or not you have access to a graphical environment. If you do, your best bet would be to grab the files from http://packages.ubuntu.com/

This is also possible from the command line as there are predictable urls. For instance:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_0.7.25.3ubuntu9.4_i386.deb
```

You can find the correct version and whether the package is in `main` or `universe` by using `apt-cache policy`.

This is of course scriptable. Here's a quick one:

```
#! /bin/bash
PACKAGE=$1
URI=`apt-cache show $PACKAGE | grep "Filename:" | cut -f 2 -d " "`
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/$URI
```

Comment: i don't have gui and of course i know that i can download packages manualy.

Comment: ok, there is an option `--print uris`, but it works fine only with `download` action. There is also a `filename` field in `apt-cache show pkg`, which i could wget, but it is absent in the older version...

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for then. You are aware that the feature you want isn't available in the version of apt that you have, you can't install new packages (so any non-default application is out of the question), and you don't want to use `wget`. I added a quick script that find the correct url and pass it to `wget`. Beyond that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @disfated I assume the system you're working on (the one local to you) has a GUI. Why not find the links locally (from packages.ubuntu.com) and paste the URLs over SSH (for `wget`)?

Comment: @andrewsomething oh, there is a "Filename" field in my apt-cache - at first i didn't notice it. it's ok now - i have uri and have wget installed. thank you and all responders :)

Comment: @Oli, i don't like the idea of doing what the computer can do - this is kind of challange and there likely will be much reusage in future

Answer (score 18):

`apt-get download [package]` works without root privileges but only for Ubuntu Natty and newer. You can also use `apt download [package]`.

If you've got `aptitude` installed, you can run use `aptitude download [package]`

Comment: Do not have `aptitude` installed

Comment: `apt` is a Java tool. - I edited your answer because you were almost there. I tested `apt-get download banshee` as a normal user and it works just fine (downloads the package to the current path).

Comment: Ah. I've reverted the edit because I've just found out that version 0.7.23 of `apt-get` doesn't have a download function.

Comment: @Oli `man apt` gives me a manual of a java application ,indeed (strange). However, if you type `apt` in a terminal, you'll notice that it's about the same thing as aptitude and apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

If there are many variants, then download all

```
 #! /bin/bash

 PACKAGE=$1
 apt-cache show $PACKAGE | grep "Filename:" | while read -r line; do URI=`echo "${line}" | cut -f 2 -d " "`; wget "http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/$URI"; done
```

Comment: how does this answer the question?