# Where to find files downloaded with apt-get?

Tags: installation, apt, conky

I am trying to follow a post on another forum for installing conky on Zorian 7 (Ubuntu 13), anyway I did the *sudo apt-get* thing, then the directions say to "copy files x1, x2,x3 to the home folder".

The problem is it doesn't say where the files are located, and I can't find them.

I've used the terminal cmds, locate, find, and a couple of others I don't remember now.

I've already asked several other questions on the other site today, and feel bad about asking another one. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Right now we can not help you, because you didn't give us all the necessary information. Could you show us the link of that forum at least?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is apparently about a non-official derivative of Ubuntu, "Zorian 7".

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use apt-get to only download packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47865/how-do-i-use-apt-get-to-only-download-packages)

Answer (score 3):

Your question was very vague: you don't explain what "the files" are.

If you're looking for the installation packages, you'll find them in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, but if you're looking for anything else you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: @AcerDeVille Don't forget to [mark the answer as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1137/how-do-i-accept-an-answer), so this question remains as *answered*. Thanks!

Comment: Don't see how that is the answer you were looking for, since it only listed the packages but not contents of packages...

Comment: @lobi The original question was far more vague.  My answer answered that one.