# How to download software from the Ubuntu app directory?

Tags: apt, software-center, software-installation

I don't want to use `sudo apt-get 'softwareName'` to install software on a Ubuntu machine. Instead I want to go to https://apps.ubuntu.com search for the software then download and install it later like Windows.

So, how to download software from Ubuntu app directory?

Comment: Just out of curiosity's sake, why not use `apt-get`?

Comment: That question only have methods for apt-get. Is related but not duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu contrary to Windows, doesn't have installer for most of the software but package. The packages are installed along with dependencies in a orderly fashion (A depends of B, hence B gets installed first, then I can install A) that are contrary to windows behavior of "a installer that includes all". The only method is hunt down the individual packages (figuring out it's name and location) download them, and install them manually.

Related:

- [How do I use apt-get to only download packages?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47865/how-do-i-use-apt-get-to-only-download-packages)