# How can I obtain the default configuration files of apache2?

Tags: apache2, configuration

I need to obtain the default configuration files of a fresh, vanilla apache2. Is there any way or place to obtain them? Any help is appreciated.

Note: Other than the objective of [this similar question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/26228) I do **not** want to mess with the current existing apache2 installation in any way, shape, or form. I just want to learn the content of the default configuration files in order to compare them to the current configuration.

Comment: [Related question, but not a duplicate](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47865/how-do-i-use-apt-get-to-only-download-packages)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The straightforward way:

1. Go to [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/)
2. Search for package name
3. Open the package page, e.g, [apache2](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/apache2)
4. Click on architecture, and [download](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/i386/apache2/download)
5. Create temporary folder: `mkdir apache_temp`
6. Run `dpkg -x apache2_2.4.6-2ubuntu2_i386.deb apache_temp`
7. Default configuration files are located under `apache_temp/etc/apache2`.

Comment: Easier way: `apt-get download apache2`, and continue from step 5.